# customize login in Laravel Breeze

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-ui, laravel-breeze

I want to customize Laravel Breeze's login logic and users can login with username and mobile for example,
in previous version of Laravel, login logic uses `AuthenticatesUser` trait and I could override methods and customize easily, but now there is no trait and method to override.
What should I do now?
I search for this, and  someone suggest edit the entire login logic to the previous version but I don't think its true and there is some way that I can do that without edit the whole login logic.

Comment: If you look [at the breeze service provider](https://github.com/laravel/breeze/blob/1.x/src/Console/InstallCommand.php) it just copies the files to your project, they're not managed by a vendor. the trait you're discussing is completely removed and the authentication logic has been refactored. so in short, yes, you'd have to re-write the flow your self if you want to backport it to be similar to previous laravel versions.

Comment: i think best way for me is using laravel ui version 3 instead of laravel breeze.

Answer (score 0):

The logic now is in `Http/Controllers/Auth/AuthenticatedSessionController.php` in `$request->authenticate();` which is located in `Http/Requests/Auth/LoginRequest.php`
change `$this->only('email', ...)` to `'username'` and validation also below it